# I am unable to access condition set up in component-1 by Subject of rxjs in component-2

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AdminRoleLocalService {
    public newRoleAdded = new Subject<boolean>();
    constructor() {}
       newRoleAddedEvent() {
       this.newRoleAdded.next(true);
    }
}
```

component-1:

```
submitAddRoleForm(addRoleForm: AddRoleData) {
    this.isFetching = true;
    this.roleService.addRoleData(addRoleForm).subscribe(
    httpResponse => {
       console.log(httpResponse);
       this.isFetching = false;
       this.roleLocalService.newRoleAddedEvent();
       this.router.navigate(["/role-management"]);
    },
    errorMessage => {
     console.log(errorMessage);
     this.errorMessageContent(errorMessage);
    }
   );
}
```

component-2:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.roleLocalService.newRoleAdded.subscribe(flag => {
      this.newRoleAddedFlag = flag;
   });
}
```

> i am seeing newRoleAddedFlag as undefined where as i am expecting value as True. I am unable to find out where i am seeing. Request you to help me out.

Comment: please format your code and give more details about the error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using

```
public newRoleAdded = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
```

In this case you not need to set initial value and second component will wait for `next` method call. Or you can use

```
public newRoleAdded = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
```

And access via method:

```
getNewRoleAddedObservable(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.newRoleAdded.pipe(filter(value => value !=null)).asObservable();
}
```

Never expose subjects public this is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time on this for both of you...i got it worked. and also thanks for your suggestion on not using public of subjects.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
public newRoleAdded = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

`BehaviorSubject`is a `Subject`-like observable. But you initiate your observable with a value and when you subscribe to it, you get the last value.

Comment: It would be helpful for the asker why a BehaviourSubject could help in this scenario...

Comment: you are right. I will explain it quickly. But there is not enough info to know if it will fix its problem...

Comment: thanks for for your response.....now this. newRoleAddedFlag  is always true when i reload the component-2 which should not be a case right, it should become true only user add a role in component-1 there i am calling a method from service which is setting that flag as true. then immediately user will be redirected to component-2 page where that flag should be true otherwise it should show either undefined or false which is default value in component-2 before subscribe to subject variable.

Comment: based on that flag, i would like to swap some system messages. when user added a role successfully(component-1) then on the main page(component-2) which loads added role data automatically and show message like role is added successfully. when user loads main page without adding role then message should say that all available roles are loaded successfully..i need to acheive this..actually. the wonder is that i used SUBJECT OF RXJS in smilar way for some other purpose with .next() it is working fine there in other components,,but failing in this case...

Comment: Hi , i am getting it now by initialing it with 'NULL' value - public newRoleAdded = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);